# plotting a list of arrays with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a list `raws` of arrays that I would like to plot in ipython notebook. Here is the code I am trying to get working:

```
fig, axes = subplots(len(raws),1, sharex=True, tight_layout=True, figsize=(12, 6), dpi=72)
for r in range(len(raws)):
    axes[r].plot(raws)
```

I've been lost for hours if not days trying to figure out how to index the list `raws`, such that I can plot each mxn array on it's own axis where n is the number of time points, i.e., x-axis and m is the number of time-series functions sampled at each point.

When I code:

```
for r in range(len(raws)):
        axes[r].plot(raws[r])
```

I get an ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

For your information:

```
    len(raws) = 2
    type(raws) = 'list'
    np.shape(raws[0][0]) = (306, 10001)
    raws = 
[(array([[ -4.13211217e-12,  -4.13287303e-12,  -4.01705259e-12, ...,
          1.36386023e-12,   1.65182851e-12,   2.00368966e-12],
       [  1.08914129e-12,   1.47828466e-12,   1.82257607e-12, ...,
         -2.70151520e-12,  -2.48631967e-12,  -2.28625548e-12],
       [ -7.80962369e-14,  -1.27119591e-13,  -1.73610315e-13, ...,
         -1.13219629e-13,  -1.15031720e-13,  -1.12106621e-13],
       ..., 
       [  2.52774254e-12,   2.32293195e-12,   2.02644002e-12, ...,
          4.20064191e-12,   3.94858906e-12,   3.69495394e-12],
       [ -4.38122146e-12,  -4.96229676e-12,  -5.47782145e-12, ...,
          3.93820033e-12,   4.18850823e-12,   4.34950629e-12],
       [ -1.07284424e-13,  -9.23447993e-14,  -7.89852400e-14, ...,
          7.92079631e-14,   5.60172215e-14,   3.04448868e-14]]), array([ 60.   ,  60.001,  60.002, ...,  69.998,  69.999,  70.   ])), (array([[ -6.71363108e-12,  -5.80501003e-12,  -4.95944514e-12, ...,
         -3.25087343e-12,  -2.68982494e-12,  -2.13637448e-12],
       [ -5.04818633e-12,  -4.65757005e-12,  -4.16084140e-12, ...,
         -4.26120531e-13,   2.20744290e-13,   7.81245614e-13],
       [  1.97329506e-13,   1.64543867e-13,   1.32679812e-13, ...,
          2.11645494e-13,   1.94795729e-13,   1.75781773e-13],
       ..., 
       [  3.04245661e-12,   2.28376461e-12,   1.54118900e-12, ...,
         -1.14020908e-14,  -8.04647589e-13,  -1.52676489e-12],
       [ -1.83485962e-13,  -5.22949893e-13,  -8.60038852e-13, ...,
          7.70312553e-12,   7.20825156e-12,   6.58362857e-12],
       [ -7.26357906e-14,  -7.11700989e-14,  -6.88759767e-14, ...,
         -1.04171843e-13,  -1.03084861e-13,  -9.68462427e-14]]), array([ 60.   ,  60.001,  60.002, ...,  69.998,  69.999,  70.   ]))]
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you encountering an error? Does it look funky?

Comment: If you just want on each subplot to have ~300 lines, change `axes[r].plot(raws)` to `axes[r].plot(raws[r])`. That gives me two plots with lots of lines on each. Otherwise, it's not clear to me what kind of plots you want.

Comment: @Bill I encounter a _italic_ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence._italic_ with either `axes[r].plot(raws) to axes[r].plot(raws[r])`.

Comment: @mdscruggs all I get are empty axes.

Answer (score 5):

Just so I can post code, I am responding here.

Looks like your data is nested in the form

```
[ ( array1, array2, ..., arrayN ) ]
```

This could be handled in one of two ways:

```
In [2]: raws = [np.random.rand(20, 100), np.random.rand(20, 100)]

In [3]: raws = raws[0]

In [4]: f, axes = plt.subplots(len(raws), 1)

In [5]: for i in range(len(raws)):
   ...:     axes[i].plot(raws[i])
```

Or

```
In [3]: raws = [(np.random.rand(20, 100), np.random.rand(20, 100))]

In [4]: f, axes = plt.subplots(len(raws[0]), 1)

In [5]: for i in range(len(raws[0])):
   ...:     axes[i].plot(raws[0][i])
```

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce your code, but for some reason this doesn't work with my version of 'raws' which is also of type 'list'. Interestingly though when I run `raws[0].shape` I get AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'. I am not exactly sure what a 'tuple' is?!

Comment: Tuples are immutable list objects: `(1, 2, 3)` as opposed to `[1, 2, 3]`. How did you create your `raws` object? It looks like your numpy arrays are nested in tuples in a list.

Comment: The `raws` object was created using output from a class function of a (little known python) module that reads binary files containing multi-sensor time series data. I'm sorry but I really don't know what else to tell you. Here is a link to the [function](http://martinos.org/mne/generated/mne.fiff.Raw.html)

Comment: Hmm, seems like the data is just in the form `[ ( array1, ..., arrayN ) ]`. Check out the edited post and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a list of arrays such as `abac` below, you can plot as following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(20))
b = a * 2
c = a * 3
abac = a,b,a,c

plt.plot(*abac)
```